# Net.Msmq Binding Not Picking Up Messages in Queue as soon as the application pool gets recycled

Tags: asp.net, wcf, netmsmqbinding, msmq-wcf

"when the application  pool is "alive" the service  picks up the messages  correctly, but as soon as the application pool  gets recycled  (because of timeout or any other reason), the service stops picking  up the messages, that just sit
 in the queue until the service starts again by browsing to the service webpage"

Have you find a solution, to activate the service without manualy browse the service.

Comment: did you tried ? tried http://keithelder.net/blog/archive/2009/06/03/fix-for-wcf-netmsmqbinding-not-picking-up-messages-in-queue.aspx http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/03/17/hosting-a-wcf-service-based-on-msmq-in-iis7/ http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/a1df55c4-e642-442a-9057-f0aec278d10c/ and other ones)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to configure [auto-start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285(v=azure.10).aspx). Then IIS will start your service immediately without waiting for the first request.

But first you need to add [AppFabric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677212(v=azure.10).aspx) to your ISS, then you need be sure you have the "Start Mode" option in your pool advance settings.

Note: In my windows 7 IIS7 didnt work, but in my windows server 2012 R2 IIS8 Works perfectly

Also you can check this similar question:
[MSMQ WCF hosted in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617449/msmq-wcf-hosted-in-iis/35415746#35415746)