# MSMQ WCF hosted in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, msmq

I am stuck in the following case - I have two web applications – **A** and **B**. They are both running on the same computer. **B** is hosting a *netMsmqBinding* WCF Service. Also,  **B**’s application pool has just recycled itself. **A** calls **B**’s WCF service. I see that the message has arrived in the private MSMQ queue which I have created. But until I don’t browse the *.svc URL the message is not proceed by **B**. 
Am I missing something required by this technology? What is the clean way to implement such a functionality?
These are the configuration that I am using. If I missed some helpful info, please, tell me and I will provide it:
The service (B):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="MyProject.Web.Services.EmsListener">
            <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/myQueue"
                      binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyMsmqBinding"
                      contract="MyProject.Abstraction.IEmsListener">
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>




 <netMsmqBinding >
                <binding name="MyMsmqBinding"
                         durable="true"
                         receiveRetryCount="2"
                         maxRetryCycles="2"
                         retryCycleDelay="00:01:00"
                         receiveErrorHandling="Move" >
                    <security mode="None">
                        <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
                        <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="None" msmqProtectionLevel="None"  />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netMsmqBinding>
```

The client(A):

```
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
<netMsmqBinding>
                <binding name="MyBinding ">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netMsmqBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>        
            <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/myQueue" binding="netMsmqBinding"
                bindingConfiguration=" MyBinding " contract="EmsListener.IEmsListener"
                name=" MyBinding " />

        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because IIS is not starting your application after recycled.

Possible solution is to configure [auto-start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260%28v=azure.10%29.aspx). Then IIS will start your service immediately without waiting for the first request.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution of Imortist  works!!

But first you need to add [AppFabric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677212(v=azure.10).aspx) to your ISS, then you need be sure you have the "Start Mode" option in your pool advance settings.

Note: In my windows 7 IIS7 didnt work, but in my windows server 2012 R2 IIS8 Works perfectly